# Moving away from Scientific Linux

Tags: fedora, rhel, backup, upgrade, scientific-linux

I am running Scientific Linux 7 with xfce in office... it took quite a while to get my environment productive (DevOps, ML Development python/miniconda, ...) and as this is for business not only private use I am interested to keep being productive in the most effective way.

As Scientific Linux is discontinued I have to get my things packed and move over to another distro which will be CentOS or more likely Fedora 30 (or any other Desktop-able RHEL 8 compatible distro). Things which I do on my workstation right now:

- Logical Volumes for / and /home dynamically resized to fit my workload
- running Postgres 11 Instance for development
- Miniconda Environments for geoscience and torch for ml/dl tasks
- terraform and ansible for cloud deployment and automation
- ssh keyring setup
- xfce Desktop on two screens
- VPN Connections to some of our clients
- Remmnia as RDP Client with a lot of configured connections I don't want to loose
- ... and so on

My question is how to safely get most of my tweaks over to the fresh installed distro?

1. Do I even need to format the /home partition?
2. If I don't format it and use the same usernames, will my ~/ Folder find its way back?
3. Better just copy data and profiles onto an external disk and copy back the things I need in the moment I really need it (I am afraid that I will have to keep this backup for years)?
4. which other parts of the filesystem should I backup? (How to know where for example Remmnia is saving its connection configurations)
5. Is there a dnf command to quickly export a list of installed packages which can be used for reinstall on the fedora machine then?

Generally: How would YOU do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do I even need to format the /home partition?

   > You don't *need* to, but...
2. If I don't format it and use the same usernames, will my ~/ Folder find its way back?

   > Yes.  But the format and options of configuration files will likely be different in many places.  So when you just use the new distro with the old config, things will break.
   >   You could create a new user with a new home and copy config-files over one by one to see what breaks or needs changes.  Happy `chown`-ing...
3. Better just copy data and profiles onto an external disk and copy back the things I need in the moment I really need it (I am afraid that I will have to keep this backup for years)?

   > Yes, backups are a must-have in your situation.
4. which other parts of the filesystem should I backup? (How to know where for example Remmnia is saving its connection configurations)

   > `/etc`, `/home`,  any data-bases you are working with.  The list of installed packages will be useful, but be aware that package-names (and versions) might be different between distros.  If you have installed things from outside your distro, keep note of the additional repos (that should be in `/etc`, but you should double-check).

Hope that helps!

Comment: In step 2, many programs can handle older configuration files. There’s no need to create a new user, the old home directory can be renamed and a new one created (with copies of the skeleton files).

Comment: Accepted this, because it answered my main question 1) and 2) and therefore gave me a good idea what might be the correct path to take. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with Scientific Linux, the closest would be CentOS. Fedora is quite a few steps ahead in software versions, that could be a problem adjusting.

You can try `dnf list --installed` to get a list of installed packages. You'd need to edit out exact versions and keep architectures to be able to take the list to install equivalent packages later.

I have had to reinstall busted Fedora installations. I saved configuration (essentially `/etc`), installed over the system (being careful not to format `/home`), installed the saved list of packages, and restored accounts and such form saved `/etc`. At least that is how I remember it, it was quite a time back. And it didn't involve different distributions.